# Insert an element after a specific element in a List of strings

Tags: python, list

I need to add "NA" after specific keywords in my list of strings. Is there a loop to do so? I found a post showing how to add an element before a specific element but not AFTER.

My Example:

Input: new_ls1

```
Output:
['Breakdown',
 'ttm',
 '6/30/2020',
 '6/30/2019',
 '6/30/2018',
 '6/30/2017',
 'Total Revenue',
 '4
5
4
3

 'Cost of Revenue',
 '2
3
4
3
2

 'Gross Profit',
 '2
3
2
1
2
]
```

I want to add "NA" after "Gross Profit" and Cost of Revenue" and save the result in new_ls2

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Please note that you should post the code you have tried to use for this purpose and seek help in how to fix what is not working. SO is a place where others write code for you.

Comment: @epsi95 The desired output is a website scraper, which I try to program for training purpose

Comment: @SinanÜnür: sorry I will do so with the next question but I just have very limited experience and didn't know where to start

Answer (score 3):

I would create iterator:

```
def add_na(words):
   for each in words:
       yield each
       if each in ("Gross Profit", "Cost of Revenue"):
           yield "NA"

result = list(add_na(my_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the wrong data structure. Instead of having a single flat list to represent a table, I would recommend a more structured approach:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

table = {
    'name': 'Breakdown',
    'headings':
    [
        'ttm',
        'Total Revenue',
        'Cost of Revenue',
        'Gross Profit',
    ],
    'columns':
    [
        [
            '6/30/2020',
            '6/30/2019',
            '6/30/2018',
            '6/30/2017',
        ],
        [
            '153,284,000',
            '143,015,000',
            '125,843,000',
            '110,360,000',
            '89,950,000',
        ],
        [
            '48,510,000',
            '46,078,000',
            '42,910,000',
            '38,353,000',
            '34,261,000',
        ],
        [
            '104,774,000',
            '96,937,000',
            '82,933,000',
            '72,007,000',
            '55,689,000',
        ],
    ],
}

columns = ['Gross Profit', 'Cost of Revenue']
indexes = map(lambda x: table['headings'].index(x), columns)

for i in indexes:
    table['columns'][i].insert(0, 'NA')

print(table)
```